# Differential equation and exact solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Given a differential equation $y'(t)=f(t,y(t))$, where f satisfies the condition $(u-v)(f(t,u)-f(t,v))\le0$ for all $u$ and $v$.

If $U(t)$ and $V(t)$ are exact solutions, I want to show that $|U(t)-V(t)|\le|U(0)-V(0)|$. Can I prove it in this way: if $U(0)$ and $V(0)$ are exact solutions, then they are equal. If $U(0)$ and $V(0)$ are not exact solutions, then they are larger than $|U(t)-V(t)|$.

And also how can I use this result, to prove that two numerical solutions $u_n$ and $v_n$ generated by implicit Euler satisfy $|u_n-v_n|\le|u_0-v_0|$ for all $n\ge0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
\bigl((U-V)^2\bigr)'&=2(U-V)(U'-V')\\
&=2(U-V)\bigl((f(t,U)-f(t,V)\bigr)\\
&\le0.
\end{align}$$
Thus, $(U-V)^2$ is decreasing and $(U(t)-V(t))^2\le(U(0)-V(0))^2$, $t\ge0$.

For Euler's method:
$$\begin{align}
(u_{n+1}-v_{n+1})^2&=\bigl((u_n-v_n)+h(f(t_n,u_n)-f(t_n,v_n))\bigl)^2\\
&=(u_n-v_n)^2+2\,h\,(u_n-v_n)(f(t_n,u_n)-f(t_n,v_n))+h^2(f(t_n,u_n)-f(t_n,v_n))^2\\
&\le(u_n-v_n)^2.
\end{align}$$

Comment: I got it! Thanks! But what about the solutions that generated by implicit Euler method? We can't differentiate discrete variables.

Comment: See the edited answer.

Comment: I don't understand why if it is decreasing, then it is smaller than $u_0-v_0$. Could you please elaborate it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Iterate. If a sequence is decreasing, the first term is the largest.

Comment: Oops...I wasn't thinking straight.. Thanks!

Comment: Given a differential equation $y'(t)=f(t,y(t))$, where f satisfies the condition $(u-v)(f(t,u)-f(t,v))\le0$ for all $u$ and $v$.And $y_n$ is the exact solution while $u_n$ is the solution generated by implicit Euler with $u_0=y_0$. I am wondering if the following statement is true: $|u_n-y_n|\le nh^2y''/2$?