# Perturbed differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Given a differential equation $y'(t)=f(t,y(t))$, where f satisfies the condition $(u-v)(f(t,u)-f(t,v))\le0$ for all $u$ and $v$. Suppose $W$ satisfies a perturbed differential equation $W'=f(t,W(t))+r(t)$ for $t\ge0$. I need to show that $|U(t)-W(t)|\le|U(0)-W(0)|+\int_0^t|r(s)|ds$.

I think that to show $|U(t)-W(t)|\le|U(0)-W(0)|+\int_0^t|r(s)|ds$, I can first  show that $|U(t)-W(t)|\le|U(0)-W(0)|$ and then show that $\int_0^t|r(s)|ds\ge0$. Am I on the right track?

Comment: What is $U(t)$?

Comment: I think $U(t)$ is the exact solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
(U-W)(U'-W')&=(U-W)\bigl((f(y,U)-f(t,W)-r(t)\bigr)\\
&=(U-W)(f(y,U)-f(t,W))-(U-W)\,r(t)\\
&\le-(U-W)\,r(t)
\end{align}$$
From here
$$
|U'-W'|\le r(t)
$$
and
$$\begin{align}
|U(t)-W(t)|&\le|U(0)-W(0)|+\int_0^t|U'(s)-W'(s)|\,ds\\
&\le|U(0)-W(0)|+\int_0^t|r(s)|\,ds.
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks! Could you also take a look at this similar problem http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1747043/differential-equation-and-exact-solutions? I really appreciate it!